# FBRequest not returning user birthdate

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, userinfo

I'm using Facebook SDK v.3.18.2

I only wants user's first name, last name, email and *date of birth*, **I'm getting everything except date of birth**.

I'm surely doing wrong with the permission? Not sure.

Here's some code to help you find out my problem,

```
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         // Call the sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];

// This method will handle ALL the session state changes in the app
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError     *)error
{
    // If the session was opened successfully
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
        NSLog(@"Session opened");
        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

//            This is not working though I'm putting it as comment
//            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
//             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
//               NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
//               NSError *error) {
//                 if (!error) {
//                     NSLog(@"User Info : %@",user);
//                 }
//             }];
        
        [[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",result);
        }];
    }
    return;
}
```

Here's Output Log:

```
{
    email = "email@domain";
    "first_name" = Hemang;
    gender = male;
    id = someId;
    "last_name" = Shah;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/someId/";
    locale = "en_US";
    name = "Hemang Shah";
    timezone = "5.5";
    "updated_time" = "some date and time";
    verified = 1;
}
```

But date of birth is missing, I've it set in my profile too.

## Update:

Tried with the following permissions **NOT WORKED!**

"user_birthdate" or
"birthday"

Answer (score 2):

```
 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_birthday",@"public_profile"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                  switch (state) {
                                      case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {

                                                  NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);                                                      NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                                                                         user.location[@"name"]]);

                                              }
                                          }];
                                          break;

                                      case FBSessionStateClosed:
                                      case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                                          [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                          break;

                                      default:
                                          break;
                                  }

                              } ];
```

need ref : [use this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#permissions)

the console output is : [image]

i attached the sample project and check that `- (IBAction)loginwithCustomButaction:(id)sender`  [the project link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/ujrrgp)

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask for `"user_birthday"` along with `public_profile` .

Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-public_profile) at facebook docs

Public profile request covers

- id
- name
- first_name
- last_name
- link
- gender
- locale
- age_range

Note that you will have to get your app reviewed if you ask for any extra permission other than default public profile.